# Can all the Core Annotations be used for TokensRegex pattern matching apart from the standard annotations (word,tag,lemma,ner,normalized)?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am looking for matching `TokenRegex` with `CoreAnnotations.CoNLLDepAnnotation` and `CoreAnnotations.GovernorAnnotation` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the CoreAnnotations can be used with TokensRegex, depending on the type of annotation.  TokensRegex can be used with any of the string or number types.

It should work with the `CoreAnnotations.GovernorAnnotation`  or "governer" annotation (see [AnnotationLookup.java](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/f569983c8ad4e7890139b77775865cce1b82d4dc/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/AnnotationLookup.java) for corresponding names of the annotation).  If you are using TokensRegex rules, you can also specify your one name:

```
gov = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$GovernorAnnotation" }
{ pattern: ( [ { gov:"G" } ] ),
  results: ... }
```